# Excel: get entire row from another file’s named table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Assume I’ve got this table (named table: `tbl_source`) in `source.xlsx`

[image]

As depicted, this table might grow in size horizontally. My goal is to get all entries from row 2 into another excel file `sink.xlsx`. Any time someone will create a new column in `source.xlsx` this should be reflected in `sink.xlsx`.

Is this possible without VBA?

Comment: Do you want to just reflect a single row or the entire table? If a single row, what are the criteria that determine which row to pull into the other file?

Comment: Yes it is. See the `INDEX` function

Comment: @FlexYourData I only want a single row to be reflected (all entries from row 2). Yet, flexible. That means if user will columns in `source.xlsx` (see screenshot column D), this should also be reflected/expanded in `sink.xlsx`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That seems not to work....

Comment: What do you mean by **That**?   What do you mean by **seems not to work**?  It seems to work fine here.  I enter a row number, and the row is displayed. I add a column to `tbl_source` and that additional column is also displayed.  I suspect there is relevant information that you have not shared, or that you have not implemented the function properly.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Do you mind sharing that formula?

Comment: What do you mean by ***That***? What do you mean by ***seems not to work***? The formula is something like `index(table_ref,row_num,0)`

Comment: that 0 made the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For getting a particular row, one for which you have a value for the start of that row, or a row number (in the data, so it's row 6 of the data, or it's the data on row 22, no matter what row of the table that is), you can easily get that row.

For instance, `VLOOKUP()` can do it. You'd need the value in the first column, that'd be the lookup value that it hinges on, and do it like:

```
=VLOOKUP($C$14,$A$1:$G$5,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS($A$1:$G$5)),FALSE)
```

(where your table is A1:G5). The `COLUMNS()` phrase in the `SEQUENCE()` function is what makes sure added columns are automatically included. (If  you want to make that more rock solid, you can add a column or two to the range value (make the `COLUMNS()` parameter "wider"... A1:J5 for example... so that inserting columns works its magic, though just "using" columns would strain that), figuring anyone adding a column will do it in the range, or use the next column, not skip, oh, eight columns, and use one, just subtract that extra amount from the `COLUMNS()` parameter.) If the data has headers, you can use a range of them AND some extra columns, like say 30 extras, inside a `COUNTA()` function to keep count of the used columns, adding some value for any known to have no header.

Using the row number can be done with the following formula concept if you convert it to a relative row in the table (so the example range, just use it directly, but say the table starts on row 10, you'd subtract 9):

```
=OFFSET(A1,C17-1,0,1,COLUMNS(A1:G5))
```

(where C17 would have the absolute row value).

Those two basic approaches will do you just fine. (You could even use `FILTER()` with the "matches" parameter set to `<>""` which cuts off all the extra columns in the wide range (wide so it allows for expansion at its edge). But that would also drop desired cells that happen to be empty so... you'd have to fit it to the data which is often not just tricky, but also easily ruined.)

And undoubtedly, Ron Rosenfeld's formula works VERY cleanly if you know the row number though not if you need to lookup a value to trigger the result.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest the most easiest method to update TABLE form another, works between tow identical TABLEs.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Create TABLE in WB named SOURCE.xlsm.
- Another TABLE in WB named SINK.xlsm.
- Enter this Formula in cell F41 of WB SINK.xlsm &
  fill across the TABLE.

  `=IF([SOURCE.xlsm]Sheet1!ISBLANK(F30),"",F30)`

**N.B.**

- As soon you enter data in Table1 in SOURCE Workbook, formula in Table2 will update the cells.
- Since Excle TABLEs are dynamic, therefore automatically adjust New columns and Rows.
- This method will work between two Dynamic Named Range also.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: I know this approach, yet I only want a single row from the source table to sync with another file

Comment: @Kalaschnik,,, this is what U have written above,, `My goal is to get all entries from row 2 into another excel file sink.xlsx. Any time someone will create a new column in source.xlsx this should be reflected in sink.xlsx.` It's quite confusing,,, New Column is adding more data in terms of new fields and value. Please [edit] your question and be specific that you are looking to get ONLY ROW 2 every time U add/change data or add NEW COLUMN.

Comment: @Kalaschnik,, if you want to execute the updates in particular ROW/ROWs then use the shown formula in that Row/Rows only !